# Is there a way to extract the item type from a Manifest[List[X]] in Scala?

Tags: scala

I know something is a List[_] based on the Manifest I've passed into a method, but I need to know what kind of item the list is. Is that information stored in the Manifest somewhere and can you get it out? If not, any suggestions about how to work around the issue?

(Basically, I have a Map[Manifest[_], Blah], where Blah handles cases based on the class type. Handling List[X] is composable based on X, but I need to be able to figure out what X is so I can grab its Blah value out of the map.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for typeArguments

```
scala> manifest[List[Int]]
res1: Manifest[List[Int]] = scala.collection.immutable.List[Int]

scala> res1.typeArguments
res2: List[scala.reflect.Manifest[_]] = List(Int)

scala> res2.head
res3: scala.reflect.Manifest[_] = Int

scala> res3.erasure
res4: java.lang.Class[_] = int
```

Comment: That's exactly it. I knew there had to be a way to get inside there, but didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

It is hard to tell you what to do, without a piece of example code. So from what you wrote I assume you get an A[B] as parameter. This should work like this:

```
def foo[A[B], B](x: A[B])(implicit outer: ClassManifest[A[B]], inner: ClassManifest[B]) = {
  // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have a `Manifest[List[T]]` and want to handle based on `T`? How about

```
def listType[T](m: Manifest[T]) = 
  if (m.erasure == classOf[List[_]]) m.typeArguments match {
    case List(c) if c.erasure == classOf[Int] => "it's a List[Int]"
    case List(c) if c.erasure == classOf[String] => "it's a List[String]"
    case _ => "some other List"
  } else "not a List"


scala> listType(implicitly[Manifest[List[Int]]])
res29: java.lang.String = it's a List[Int]
```